# Can't debug in Blazor Webassembly hosted

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have an Blazor Webassembly hosted Project in which I cant debug in the Frontend. The Breakpoints just dont get hit. The project once was a Blazor Server application but was then refactored into an webassembly hosted project. Ever since then, debugging the front end wouldn't work no more. Does anyone have an idea what would cause that or what i can do to be able to debug again?

I already tried debugging with the devtools but that didnt work either.

Comment: Have you setup your application as described in this article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Yes I did.

Comment: Build a new WebAssembly project and test debugging on that.  Does it have the same issue?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Nope, it works there

Comment: Work through the `Program` classes on each project and work out what is different.  My wild guess is you probably have the wrong port number in one of your configurations.